# Determine Signficant Subgroups of Data Inputs

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a large (10000 X 5001) table representing 10000 samples and 5001 different features of these samples. One of these features represents an output variable of each sample. In other words, I have 5000 input variables and one output variable for each sample.

I know that most of these inputs are irrelevant. Therefore, what I would like to do is determine the subset of input variables that predicts the output variable best. What is the best/simplest way to go about doing this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). In the `Explorer` load the data and then go to the `Select attributes` tab. There you will find several options to get the most informative attributes/features in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You may want Principal Component Analysis (stats::prcomp) or Linear Discriminant Analysis (MASS::lda).

See this document by Avril Coghlan

http://little-book-of-r-for-multivariate-analysis.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking 'random' suggestions, why not go to the  [CRAN Task View for Cluster Analysis & Finite Mixture Models](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html) ?